# Change Kivy Slider Color

Tags: python, slider, kivy

Is it possible to fully customize the `Kivy` slider? Specifically, how do you change the slider background color, add a slider "fill" color, and customize the knob image/color?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is linked with the overall theme color. But you could potentially defined the color in the `kv language` files.

Comment: @Torxed Yeah, I ended up going with the `.kv` file since you can completely customize the `Slider` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been struggling with the all week since there is not much on `Kivy` style customization online, so I decided to post this question/answer here for others. It turns out you need to essentially rewrite the `Kivy` style class for `Slider`s.

Using the default style sheet from [`Kivy`'s GitHub repo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv), I found the default style `Slider` class. I then created `Color` and `BorderImage` children of the `canvas` childer under the `Slider` class, copying the existing childen to start with. Remember that `Color` applies to the next children, so you would then need a total of 5 children under `canvas` if you are completely modifying the `Slider`. Also, I had to modify the `size` attribute of the `BorderImage` so that it dynamically changes as you move the `knob`.

If you are just interested in adding a "fill" color, here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Slider>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 0
        BorderImage:
            border: (0, 18, 0, 18) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (18,
 0, 18, 0)
            pos: (self.x + self.padding, self.center_y - sp(18)) if self.orienta
tion == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - 18, self.y + self.padding)
            size: (max(self.value_pos[0] - self.padding * 2 - sp(16), 0), sp(36)
) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (sp(36), max(self.value_pos[1] - self
.padding * 2 - sp(16), 0))
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider{}_background{}'.format(self.orientation[0], '_disabled' if self.disabled else '')
''')
```

Of course, you could just as easily move the string to a `.kv` file. Let me know if you need samples for the other two customizations, but they can be done similarly.